# relocating Vector interrrupt table to SRAM for Cortex-M3?

Tags: c, arm

Every one
In my project application, am executing FreeRtos from External ddr3 memory(arm cortex-M3).
Code executed Upto VportstartFirstTask(), after this function code is not running.
below is the VportstartFirsttask which we used in our application.

```
void vPortStartFirstTask(void)
{
                                     / Use the NVIC offset register to locate the stack. /
__asm volatile(ldr r0, =0xE000ED08
ldr r0, [r0]
ldr r0, [r0]

    / Set the msp back to the start of the stack. /
    msr msp, r0
    / Call SVC to start the first task. /
    cpsie i
    svc 0
    nop
    )

}`
```

If i run the same project using some other linker file it works fine. which runs from Onchip memory it works fine.

When i am running from external memory i am facing an issue.

Can anyone help me how to relocate vector table to SRAM or any otherplace.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are only including the stack setup, not the setting of offset to SRAM. Please include all relevant code. And mind you, that is OFFSET, not the absolute address. Don't forget about TBLBASE and reserved bits. Reference: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Cihcbadd.html